# Angular select multiple not refreshing on model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have the following issue with angular and the html `select`-input:
When the user loads the page my `select` is empty until the data is loaded and returned from the corresponding service.
In this case the `select` is populated correctly.

However, the user should be able to filter the model with a click on a button.

When I press the button a new request is send to the REST-API and the response contains the new model for the `select`.

Unfortunately, the `select` won't update correctly even when I change it's model

Here is some code to illustrate my problem:

```
     // This happens in my controller
     EventService.getAvailableRooms(requestObject).then(function successCallback(response){
        // sanatizeRoomTypes is used to generate user-friendly names instead of [1, 2,..]
        vm.rooms = DataSanatizer.sanatizeRoomTypes(response.data);

    }, function errorCallback(response){


        console.log(response)
    });
```

`vm.rooms` is the model of my `select`:

```
<select id="roomSelect" ng-model="eventCtrl.selectedRooms"
                                ng-options="room.name group by room.type for room in eventCtrl.rooms track by room.id" multiple required>
</select>
```

In some cases the select duplicates it's model or looses entries. It seems like there is some sort of data binding problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your model changes in $scope.apply :

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.data.myVar = "Another value";
});
```

Read here for more info:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html

You can also use $scope.$watch on the changing $scope variables to update them in your view.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this isn't working. Same result.

Comment: Did you try using $scope.$watch like this: 

$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.data.myVar },
              function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  document.getElementById("").innerHTML =
                      "" + newValue + "";
              }
             );

Comment: The return value of the first callback should be your model, and then do your update in the second callback

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that.

Comment: You may try a module for handling your storage... maybe it will solve whawtever issue you are having.

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage